# Retrieve single value from this php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this php array `$result2` that looks like this.

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
        id => (int) 1
        username => 'asd'
        password => '123'
        fullname => 'asd'
        email_addr => 'asd@gmail.com'
    }
]
```

From `$result2`, I want to have a `$json_result` that looks like this;

```
[{"email_addr":"asd@gmail.com"}]
```

I tried 
`$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => $result2['email_addr'] ];
echo json_encode($emailAddress);`

However, the error I get is this;

> Notice (8): Undefined index: email_addr
>   [APP/Controller\DeptUsersController.php, line 126]

The output is like this which is wrong;

```
[{"email_addr":null}]
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: What line is line 126?

Comment: `$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => $result2['email_addr'] ];`

Comment: That means your $result2['email_addr'] is blank first check it is not blank then perform rest operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully `(int) 0 => object(stdClass)` It's an object, and this object is an element with index **0** of an array. So:

```
$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => $result2[0]->email_addr ];
```

Comment: Correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it's object you can't show value if using `$result2['email_addr']` you should using this `$result2->email_addr` method

Answer (score 1):

You have an `object` of type `stdClass` so you can't access directly to the field `email_addr`. Try this code:

```
$mObject = new stdClass();
$mObject = $result2[0];
$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => $mObject->email_addr ];
echo json_encode($emailAddress);
```

This should fix your error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$emailAddress[] = ['email_addr' => $result2[0]->email_addr ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_intersect_key` :

```
$wanted = ["email_addr"=>""];
$data = [
    "id" => 1,
    "username" => 'asd',
    "password" => '123',
    "fullname" => 'asd',
    "email_addr" => 'asd@gmail.com',
];
$result = array_intersect_key($wanted, $data);
var_dump($result);
```

It useful when you need one or more key to find. It more saving time